# Python error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required, although it has been already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I try to install python `numpy` package:

```
pip install numpy==1.21
```

But get an error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Please note: **The Build Tools for Visual Studio are installed**

Can you please help me to resolve the issue? :(

Full error text:

```
pip install numpy==1.21
Collecting numpy==1.21
  Using cached numpy-1.21.0.zip (10.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [208 lines of output]
      setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.0 may not yet support Python 3.10.
        warnings.warn(
      Running from numpy source directory.
      C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1i2s1np\numpy_6dc990edd9104edfb28cfdb4cc7e468e\tools\cythonize.py:69: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
        from distutils.version import LooseVersion
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1i2s1np\numpy_6dc990edd9104edfb28cfdb4cc7e468e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1i2s1np\numpy_6dc990edd9104edfb28cfdb4cc7e468e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1i2s1np\numpy_6dc990edd9104edfb28cfdb4cc7e468e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
        NOT AVAILABLE

      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\alona.\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1i2s1np\numpy_6dc990edd9104edfb28cfdb4cc7e468e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e1i2s1np\numpy_6dc990edd9104edfb28cfdb4cc7e468e\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
        FOUND:
          language = c
          define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

      Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
      C:\Users\alona.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you're seeing

> setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.0 may not yet support Python 3.10.

in the output too.

Install `numpy==1.21.6` instead.

It [has binary wheels for Python 3.10 on Windows](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.21.6/#files), so you don't need to compile it by hand, and the NumPy project is good with semver compatibility, so whatever requires `numpy==1.21.0` should be fine with `1.21.6`.

Comment: Could also add the alternative to downgrade the python version in case the numpy requirement is that strict

Answer (score 0):

Not only to install the package
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022

You have to also run the command to update the env

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
pip install numpy==1.21.0
```

Comment: The error states that it fails to install `numpy-1.21.0.zip`. How would trying to install this exact version using your command fix the error that popped up?

Answer (score -2):

Just Write In Your Terminal "pip install numpy", this will install latest version of numpy for you.

Comment: I need this version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).